# How can I optimize this combination method?

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics

I have this method that is working perfectly fine, but it's very slow, and sometimes I have to wait 15 minutes to get a good result, which is ok.  I'm wondering if I can make it faster.

Basically I'm running best fleet simulations, and I pre-calculate the possible ship combinations for specific voyages, but then I have to get the best fleet combinations for multiple voyages.

Obviously I can't use the same captain or crew in different ships because the voyages take place at the same time, and that's why there's some more conditions in each inner loop.

```
private static Ship[] GetBestFleet3(IList<Voyage> voyages)
{
    var bestRate = 0;
    var worstVariance = 100.0;
    Ship[] fleet = null;
    foreach (var ship0 in voyages[0].Ships)
    {
        foreach (var ship1 in voyages[1].Ships.Where(s1 => !s1.Equals(ship0)))
        {
            foreach (var ship2 in voyages[2].Ships.Where(s2 => !s2.Equals(ship0) && !s2.Equals(ship1)))
            {
                var variance = Statistics.Variance(ship0, ship1, ship2);
                var rate = ship0.Rate + ship1.Rate + ship2.Rate;
                if (rate >= bestRate || rate == bestRate && variance < worstVariance)
                {
                    bestRate = rate;
                    worstVariance = variance;
                    fleet = new[] { ship0, ship1, ship2 };

                    if (ship0.Rate >= 100 && ship1.Rate >= 100 && ship2.Rate >= 100)
                    {
                        return fleet;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fleet;
}
```

`voyages` is basically an array of voyages with possible ship combinations for each voyage.

Gist with all the relevant project files: https://gist.github.com/alfaproject/cb68e6fa1c21e1f93bf7

Comment: How do you compute `Ship.Rate`? Is `Variance` computed on the rate?

Comment: Each voyage has all possible ships with the rate already calculated, but if it matters, the Rate is the (minimum of 3 ship parameters) / (voyage best 'requirements')

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood you. The Variance is the standard deviation of the 3 ship rates.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid generating all the possible ships in advance. Can you tell us how you generate the ships for a given voyage?

Comment: I've tried avoiding that as well, but so far pre-calculating them is faster. Maybe I need to rework the whole thing. I will edit my question with that part of the code.

Comment: Mandatory comment for questions about optimization: `have you ran a profiler yet?` :)

Comment: Yes, I ran a profiler. I use dotTrace, and can upload snapshots if needed.

Comment: No, it's just a suggestion to optimize where it needs to be optimized, and not where we think it needs to be optimized. Often those two don't match. :(

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I can optimize much more my current algo. I probably need to redo the whole thing, but I'm lacking ideas, lol

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to go with a different approach. At the moment you're evaluating all the possible combinations, while I think it could be useful to evaluate only the meaningful ones. To do that I'd start with a two phase approach. First you can generate all the valid fleets and then you can sort them using a comparator that takes into account their Range/Variance.

This is the code you can use to generate all the possible fleets:

```
private static IEnumerable<Fleet> PossibleVoyages(IList<Captain> captains, IList<Crew> crews, int voyagesToPrepare, Fleet fleet)
{
    var possibleVoyages = new List<Fleet>();
    if(voyagesToPrepare == 0)
    {
        possibleVoyages.Add(fleet);
    }
    if(captains.Count < voyagesToPrepare || crews.Count < voyagesToPrepare)
    {
        // We cannot find any valid solution here
        return possibleVoyages;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var captain in captains)
        {
            foreach(var crew in crews)
            {
                var newFleet = fleet.Add(CreateShip(captain, crew));
                possibleVoyages.AddRange(
                    PossibleVoyages(
                        FreeCaptains(captains, newFleet),
                        FreeCrews(crews, newFleet),
                        voyagesToPrepare - 1,
                        newFleet));
            }
        }
    }
    return possibleVoyages;
}
```

I have not implemented the methods `FreeCaptains`, `FreeCrews`, and `CreateShip` but they should be obvious. `Fleet` act as an *immutable* collection of ships.

Once you get all the possible voyages you can just sort them using a comparator and Linq sort.

I'm not sure this is going to help much, but it is worth giving it a try.
A possible way to improve it is to keep track of the best fleet we generated so far and to just compare it with every fleet we generate instead of doing all the comparisons at the end. This could possibly prune a lot of solutions once you find a good one and it is definitely worth trying.

Comment: I will have a look at this aproach and let you know as soon as I have some data. It's already late here, so I'm not sure if I can get back to you today, but I will get back for sure. I've also added a Gist in the original post with my current hobby project if you want to play around. (;

Comment: I just installed Xamarin studio to do some tests. I'm going to have a look at the gists, and maybe I'll implement the alternative approach using yield returns

Comment: I just had a quick look, and I think this is similar to my first approach. The problem was that the voyages are very different in the requirements, and I ended up creating too many possible ships to go through, but maybe I missed something, and I'll have a proper look in the meanwhile. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but it looks like that with your current approach you're generating all the possible ships for all the possible voyages and then you filter them only later. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is my latest approach indeed. My first approach was months ago. (;

Comment: I see your ship has a `Voyage` property, but it does not look quite right to me. Why does it need to? I think this relationship should only be in the list of ships in a voyage. I also noticed that you could simplify `Ship` if you make it hold a reference to `ShipBase` rather than having it copy the values of its properties.

Comment: Yes, I have added those over the past few months while trying to optimize the actual combination. The code is a bit of a mess by now. Why the Voyage in Ship? Well, ideally I should have created a class called VoyageShip which would inherit from Ship, and would basically be a possible ship belonging to a voyage (includes the rating of the assigned voyage). I only did that because I was experimenting with my current way of getting combinations.

Comment: I'm not sure I would really create that subclass, but maybe I'm missing why you need to do that.

Comment: As a general comment, I think you should try to think about how many ships you will need to create with every approach and to figure out which one will work better. With the one I'm suggesting you are not going to consider several combinations (e.g. the ones with the same captain) that you are currently considering. That's why I think it could be faster.

Comment: I only did that because of my current method of getting all possible ships for each voyage. Basically the ships calculate their rating for the voyage they are 'assigned' to. I could move the rate calculation code outside of the ship class and set the rate in the constructor instead of passing in the actual voyage.

Comment: I think it would be better as it is going to separate the two different concerns of representing what a ship is and to compute the rating of the ship associated to a voyage.

Comment: I have updated the Gist with your suggestion. Should be better separated now. (:

Comment: I'm about to go offline now. I'll have a look at it tomorrow. As a note, now that you don't have to keep track of the voyage in the ships you can generate them once instead than three times. I was also thinking that maybe you could generate all the ships at the beginning, index them in a smart way (like a Dictionary <Captain, List <Ship>> and similarly for the crews) and create methods to efficiently retrieve the valid ships.

Comment: Like I told you before, that's what I first did a few months ago. I didn't have the voyage or the rating associated with the ships, but then I needed to calculate the rating of each ship in inner loops and it was killing the performance as well (remember that the same ship has a different rating in each voyage). The smart indexing could help. I'll try to look at it tomorrow too. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I have tried this way again, and it is way worse, unless I'm missing something. ):

Comment: Have you tried to profile it? It could be interesting to see where you spend most of the time

Comment: It spends most of the time calculating the rating, because the ships are built on the fly. The recursivity also kills the performance. This looks harmless, but it isn't: http://puu.sh/aEzv4/795d1e0fdf.png (also check the ship constructor, it's quite heavy, and like I said, your method creates the ships in a very heavy loop as well)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16204/discussion-between-mariosangiorgio-and-alfa).

Comment: I think we should try a different approach. Let's consider all the voyages together instead than separately. We need a data structure that lists all the captains, all the crew units and all the ship parts mapping them to a voyage. Something like captain 1 -> voyage 1, captain 2 -> no voyage, captain 3 -> voyage 2, ...., crew unit 25 -> voyage 3. Ignoring the ship parts, we have (5+25)^4 possible solutions (#captains + #units)^(#voyages +1) and we can easily filter out most of them (we just want a captain and five units per ship). As soon as we generate a valid solution we can compute its score

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented some code to compare two ships.  By doing this, you will avoid using that long statement of filtering of data.  There was also a condition which was wrong.

I am still not sure why you need the explicit three loops (you know your requirements better).

```
var totalRate = 0;
var previousStdDev = 100.0;
Ship[] fleet = null;
IEnumerable<Ship> firstShips = voyages[0].Ships.ToList();
IEnumerable<Ship> secondShips = voyages[1].Ships.ToList();
IEnumerable<Ship> thirdShips = voyages[2].Ships.ToList();
var shipCompare = new ShipComparer();
IEnumerable<Ship> filteredFirstShips = firstShips;
IEnumerable<Ship> filteredSecondShips = secondShips.Except(filteredFirstShips, shipCompare).ToList();
IEnumerable<Ship> filteredThirdShip = thirdShips.Except(secondShips, shipCompare).ToList();
filteredThirdShip = filteredThirdShip.Except(firstShips).ToList();


foreach (var firstShip in filteredFirstShips)
{
    foreach (var secondShip in filteredSecondShips)
    {
        foreach (var thirdShip in filteredThirdShip)
        {
            var stdDev = Statistics.Variance(firstShip, secondShip, thirdShip);
            var tempSum = firstShip.Rate + secondShip.Rate + thirdShip.Rate;
            if (tempSum >= totalRate && stdDev < previousStdDev)
            {
                totalRate = tempSum;
                previousStdDev = stdDev;
                fleet = new[] { firstShip, secondShip, thirdShip };

                if (firstShip.Rate >= 100 && secondShip.Rate >= 100 && thirdShip.Rate >= 100)
                {
                    return fleet;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return fleet;

internal class ShipComparer : IEqualityComparer<Ship>
{
    public bool Equals(Ship x, Ship y)
    {
        return x.Captain == y.Captain && x.Crew.Intersect(y.Crew).Any();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Ship ship)
    {
        //TODO create a unique hash code
        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The explicit 3 loops was actually me trying to optimize this for a 3 voyage scenario which is the most common and it's the one I care about the most, but it could be any amount of voyages if it helps in any way. I'm liking the pre-calculation of 'exceptions'. I'll try that and tell you exactly how many seconds I save.

Comment: Unfortunately your changes don't return any ships at all even if I change the equality comparer. I think it is because of the prefiltering. You are removing ships from the combinations that might be useful.

Comment: you need to provide test data so I can test it

Comment: I have added a Gist in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the Gist with a small optimization based on your example, and actually shaved some seconds from GetBestFleet3 which was nice. (: